# IEnumerable<T> equal ICollection<T> type check

Tags: c#, generics, contravariance

I have written a small pub / sub system for our app,

you subscribe to messages by implementing IHandle

Lets say the subscriber implements `IHandle<IEnumerable<MyType>>`

Then someone publish a message of type `ICollection<MyType>>` this should off course trigger the subscriber since a IColletion<> is of Type IEnumerable<>

But my code does not support this, a work around is that the publisher casts the ICollection to a IEnumerable but its prone to bugs in a larger team.

This is the code that does not work

```
public void Publish<T>(T message) where T : class
{
    if (config.EnableEventAggregator)
        subscribers.OfType<IHandle<T>>()
        .ForEach(s => s.Handle(message));
}
```

I want it to find the `IHandle<IEnumerable>` for all types that inherit `IEnumerable<T>`
Any ideas?

Comment: Cuong Le is right. Also 1) the body of your method may be replaced with a following line: `return subscribers.OfType<IHandle<T>>();`, 2) the questions has nothing to do with the reflection, so I'm going to remove the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define `IHandle` as *contra-variant* so that you don't need to work around:

```
interface IHandle<in T>
```

With this way it will accept all types which inherits from IEnumerable

This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx) is explained for you in detail how covariance and contra-variance work with genric